# How to download hadoop documentation of specific version?

Tags: hadoop

How can I download hadoop documentation of specific version?  I would like to have multiple version's offline documentation on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find out the links of the versions you need to download from https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/site/main/publish/docs/
2. Do svn checkout, Example
   `svn checkout https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/site/main/publish/docs/r2.5.2/`